# Can I make a non-centered UILabel maintain its position relative to a UIImageView that is being scaled?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

I've been learning the vagaries of AutoLayout through a combination of tutorials, StackOverflow browsing and experimentation. My primary goal in this endeavor is to learn how define as much of the UI as possible in Interface Builder using AutoLayout and minimal (preferably **no**) code.

What I am trying to achieve now is figure out how to have a `UILabel` (or any `UIView` subclass, really) maintain its position relative to a `UIImageView`. Here is a picture of how it is setup in IB at the moment and thus represents my intent: [Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGwyn.jpg)

I know how to set up the constraints on the `UIImageView` so that it scales in size for the device size. But I can't seem to figure out how to specify constraints that tell IB I want the vertical position of the `UILabel` to also scale in the same way. It feels like I am essentially looking for an aspect ratio constraint on the `UILabel's` vertical position.

I have tried embedding the `UILabel` and `UIImageView` within another `UIView` and setting some constraints there. The main ones of interest are:

```
    UILabel Align center X: Superview
    UILabel Top Space to: Superview Equals: 25 (as computed by IB)
```

The results for different device sizes are:
    [4 inch iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrBai.jpg)
    [5.5 inch iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhy7n.jpg)
    [iPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzJdz.jpg)

As you can see, not the intended result! What can I do? Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether you can set a proportional spacing constraint or not. However off the top of my head, you can probably add a transparent view which has constraints:

```
top aligned to imageView's top
left aligned to imageView's left 
right aligned to imageView's right
bottom aligned to label's top
height proportionally equals to imageView's height
```

Comment: This worked very well. My intuition tells me that the multiplier in the last constraint should be set to `(label.top - imageView.top) / imageView.height`. The fixed font size across iPhone models means the text doesn't scale well (at all) from the 4-inch iPhone to the 5.5-inch iPhone, but that is a separate matter to address.